# No external archives in eclipse

Tags: java, html, minecraft

I started a project for a Minecraft plugin on Eclipse, i need to build a path, for the spigot jar file. When I did my first project, there was an option called "Add External Archives" that option doesn't show up for me anymore. It only says "Configure Build Path", I need help, I have been trying all day.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse right click your project, click "Build Path" then click "Configure Build Path". Then a window like in the image attached should open. [image: BuildPath]
In this window you click "Add external jar" and navigate to your spigot server jar. Wen you have selected the jar file, you click "Apply and close".